# Magento2 - Moving or extending a module from vendor to app folder

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, composer, vendor

I have an extension Magestore_Bannerslider, which the previous developer installed using composer for magento2, The module is installed and working properly. The code is in the vendor folder

I need to add some custom code in the module but i do not want to edit anything under vendor,

Can someone let me know,

How can i extend the functionality of this module in app/design

or

How can i move the files from this extension to app/code, so that i can edit them there.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to extend this.

I created a folder "Magestore_Bannerslider" in my app/desgin/Magento/theme_name/

and copied templates folder in it

I was able to add the required customization.